# After Java OutOfMemoryError, Tomcat Won't Start

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory

After running my App in Tomcat many times, I've maxed out the PermGen memory (a problem with my quartz servlet, I suspect) and Java threw a OutOfMemoryError.  Normally, I just restart tomcat from time to time, but since this happened I'm unable to start/restart.  Tomcat is running in our qa environment and is normally started/stoped/restarted via the sbin folder.  I've tried to start tomcat using the alternative, catalina.sh run, but it says the port is being used!  That led me to suspect that tomcat was already running, but when I try to stop it, I get this error:

> SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
>   Jan 19, 2014 3:10:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
>   stopServer SEVERE: Catalina.stop:  java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ...

So, if it's not started or stopped, then what state is tomcat in?!  How can I bring it back to a startable state?

**Update**
As per Boris's comment, I've used *ps auxfww* to list processes and the only one with tomcat as the user is the following:

> tomcat    5111  8.0 29.0 2052336 556512 ?      Sl   Jan17 221:48
>   /usr/java/latest/bin/java
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -javaagent:/usr/share/tomcat/newrelic/newrelic.jar -Xmx512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/lib/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

For some reason, even as root, I can't delete the process.  I use

> sudo kill 5111

but the process is still listed after and tomcat still won't restart...

Comment: You may need to kill tomcat manually. Does it appear is `ps auxfww`?

Comment: Yes it does.  What are all these processes, and why don't they appear in ps -al?  Should I kill it there?

Comment: That's the `x` flag - it lifts the "must have a TTY" restriction that is on by default. Tomcat would not be running with a TTY. In any case yes - I would suggest you kill the root process (the `f` flag gives you the process hierarchy).

Comment: Boris is probably right, Tomcat may be running into an used port number and thus it does not start.  However, your main problem is still your OutOfMemoryError; maybe you tried a memory sizing solution too soon.  Have you diagnosed when and where is that memory being used?  Have you tried any tool like jconsole (free, coming with JDK) in order to get more information about it?  Maybe it can lead you to some coding error or bad practice with an easy solution

Comment: I've updated my post to reflect trying Boris's suggestion.  @Jorge_B The memory is being used up by a quartz servlet, which I plan to take care of after I'm at least able to run tomcat again.

Comment: Have you tried `kill -9 5111`?

Comment: That did it.  Thanks to both of you!  Yeah, so apparently default kill w/ PID sends SIGTERM, which bash ignores. Using -9 (SIGKILL) worked great!

Answer (score 0):

Read about kill [here](http://www.linux.org/threads/kill-commands-and-signals.4423/)

sudo kill -9 5111 will do the work. Tomcat is binded to 8005 port: until you kill the process with a SIGKILL signal it won't release the port (and you are not allowed to start another tomcat on this port).